# Mongoose: After finding document, iterate over a value in the document and run a new query on each

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I have one schema which contains an array of references to another schema (among other fields):

```
const RecipeIngredient = new Schema({
  ingredientId: {                 // store id ref so I can populate later
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'ingredients',
    required: true
  },
  // there are a couple other fields but not relevant here
});

const Recipe = new Schema({
  ingredients: [RecipeIngredient]
});
```

I'm trying to write a route which will first find a recipe by `_id`, populate the ingredients array (already have this working), and finally iterate over each ingredient in that array.

```
router.get('/:recipeId/testing', async (req, res) => {
  const { recipeId } = req.params
  let recipe = await Recipe
    .findById(recipeId)
    .populate({ 
      path: 'ingredients.ingredientId', 
      model: 'Ingredient',
      select: '_id ......' //I'm selecting other fields too
    })
    .lean()
    .exec();
  
  if (recipe) {
    const { ingredients } = recipe;

    const newIngredients = [];
    await ingredients.forEach(async (ingr) => {
      // here I'd like to be able to run a new query
      // and append the result to an array outside of the forEach
      // I do need information about the ingr in order to run the new query

      newIngredients.push(resultOfNewQuery);
    });
    return res.json(newIngredients)
  };
  
  return res.status(404).json({ noRecipeFound: 'No recipe found.'});
})
```

I've tried approaching this in a few different ways, and the closest I've gotten was executing the new query within each iteration, but because the query is async, I return the response before I've actually collected the documents from the inner query.

I also attempted to use `.cursor()` in the initial query, but that won't work for me because I do need to access the `ingredients` field on the `recipe` once it is resolved before I can iterate and run the new queries.

Any ideas would be appreciated!  I'm definitely opening to restructuring this whole route if my approach is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work by using a for loop:

```
const newIngredients = [];
for (let idx = 0; idx < ingredients.length; idx++) {
  const { fieldsImInterestedIn } = ingredients[idx];

  const matchingIngredients = await Ingredient
    .find(fieldsImInterestedIn)
    .lean()
    .exec()
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ noIngredientsFound: 'No ingredients found' }));

    newIngredients.push(ingredientsToChooseFrom[randomIndex]);
};

return res.json(newIngredients);
```

still a little perplexed as to why this was able to work while `forEach` wasn't, but I'll happily move on...